# How to prevent a user from pressing a submit button in Node.js / Express

Tags: node.js, express

Good day to everyone!

So, I know more or less how to to hide a button in JavaScript when it's a frond-end development. There are multiple examples. However, I've got a form in which a user is expected to type their phone number and hit a submit button. Once it's hit I want to prevent user from pressing the button multiple times therefore the button should be disabled while a user is waiting for an incoming SMS with a password.

I'm a new to programming, particularly to Node.js. I just don't know if front-end could be used in back-end or there are tools providing the same possibilities.

**p.s.** Well, I initially thought If I work with HTML in Express and can place CSS or Images into a public directory, why can I not placed a .JS file for processing some front-end tasks like controlling what numbers are pressed in a field or disabling a submit button. But then what I was confused about is that a friend of mine had told me that it can be done in Node.js. I'm wondering if it was a joke or not.

Comment: The Node.js server would have to somehow communicate to the front-end to disable the button. It's easier to just add the `disabled` attribute when the button is clicked. Maybe your friend was talking about not accepting submit requests while the SMS hasn't arrived.

Comment: Just get rid of the button, replace it with a smaller less obvious text link they can use to request a resend after n seconds have passed.

Comment: What if I use https://socket.io/ would it be possible to control the client side?